# How to set custom CSS for data-src

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

I know that we can set css for a image via  id or its class. My images in the site are coded as below

```
    <img class="img-responsive" id="loader" src="{{asset('img/loader.gif')}}" data-src="{{asset('uploads/banner01.jpg')}}" >
```

### Attributes of the images

- loader.gif

  ```
      Width:200px
      Height:200px
  ```
- banner01.jpg

  ```
     Width:500px
     Height:400px
  ```

### Custom CSS added via loader id

```
#loader{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
      }
```

My problem is that when I add this custom CSS it works fine with `200px` width and `200px` of height but it also explicable to banner01.jpg too.

***Means even banner width 500px and height 400px after loading image it shows as a 200px X 200px image.***

### What I want to know

Is there is a way to add custom css to `data-src` ?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better solution to load images, videos and contents after page rendered called lazy load.
There is a very simple JQuery plugin to implement that with very few lines of codes.

http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

There are only 3 steps.

1. Add CDN or download and link the plugin.

   2.Add "lazy" to class attribute of img tag.

   EG:
   `<img class="lazy" data-src="images/1.jpg" />`

3.Add this JQuery function.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.lazy').lazy();
  });
       </script>
```

To add a gif for loading just change your function to this.

```
// plugin build-in placeholder management
    $(function() {
        $('.lazy').lazy({
            placeholder: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEALAPQAPzl5uLr9Nrl8e7..."
        });
    });
```

For a demo check this link.
  http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Answer (score 2):

You will try below custom css

```
img:not([data-src$="loader.gif"]) {
   Width:500px
   Height:400px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But my site contain more than 100 images and they are getting generated from DB. so its hard to say which image may load .Sometimes it may banner01.jpg and sometimes it may banner100.jpg. Do you have any idea for that]

Comment: You may try :not as below img:not([class="top-text"]) {//your css}

Comment: You can simply use `img[data-drc*="banner"]{ }` this will match all containing banner in name of data-src

Answer (score 1):

I think you should load these two images to two image tags. And put it in the same div.
And put this css id to div.

```
<div id="loader">

   <img class="img-responsive" src="{{asset('img/loader.gif')}}">
   <img class="img-responsive" data-src="{{asset('uploads/banner01.jpg')}}" style="width:500px;height:400px">

</div>
```

Comment: Its not working. When I updated my code as you mentioned loading.gif load but image never gonna visible in the div. It always display the loader.gif only